# IScroll5 use for classes instead of ids

Tags: jquery, class, iscroll

I know it's been asked quite a few times in this forum, but I haven't found a single solution that works.

I have multiple ids with the same class I want the IScroll to be applied on.

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">
 // content
</div>
<div id="myid-differentname" class="myclass">
 // content 
</div>
```

However, I cannot change the ids, and they are not in increasing number like myId1, myId2, etc... they have full names.

Looking at another thread in this forum ([Trigger iScroll 4 on all elements with a certain Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584491/trigger-iscroll-4-on-all-elements-with-a-certain-class)) I haven't been able to make it work.

The code I used is (based on that thread):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var myScroll = new Array();

   $('.myclass').each(function(){
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            myScroll.push(new IScroll(id, { mouseWheel: true, scrollbars: true, interactiveScrollbars: true, scrollbars: 'custom' }););
    });
});
```

Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this worked for me:

```
var scrollName = new Array();
var scrollId = new Array();

$('.myclass').each(function(index) {
    scrollId[index] = $(this).attr('id');
    setTimeout(function() {
        scrollName[index] = new IScroll(scrollId[index], {
            mouseWheel: true,
            scrollbars: true,
            interactiveScrollbars: true
            scrollbars: 'custom'
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

It worked with iScroll 4, but I think no problem with version 5.

———————————————————————————————————————

**UPDATE 1**

**Multiple iScrolls by class**

In iScroll 5 you can use a class as selector:

```
var scroller = new Array();

$('.myclass').each(function(){

myScroller = new IScroll(this, {
    scrollX: false,
    scrollY: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    scrollbars: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: true 
});

scroller.push(myScroller);
});
```

The different scrollers can be triggered with:

```
scroller[0].scrollTo(0, -100, 500);
scroller[1].scrollTo(0, -200, 500);
```

So you don't need to specify an id. As long as you don't want different options.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kapetan/GuCC2/13/)

———————————————————————————————————————

**UPDATE 2**

**Multiple iScrolls by id**

Here is a working example by using multiple id selectors

```
var scroller = new Array();
var selfId = new Array();

$('.myclass').each(function(){

selfId = $(this).attr('id');
myScroller = new IScroll('#' + selfId, {
    scrollX: false,
    scrollY: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    scrollbars: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: true 
});

scroller.push(myScroller);
console.log(selfId.toString());
```

});

The different scrollers can be triggered with:

```
scroller[0].scrollTo(0, -100, 500);
scroller[1].scrollTo(0, -200, 500);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kapetan/tCang/2/)

Comment: Will try it later on tonight and get back here

Comment: you also forgot a comma after inactiveScrollbars, but again it's not working :/

Comment: Updated my answer, maybe this will help to go on.

Comment: thanks! :) will try it tomorrow, but judging from the fiddle this is all I wanted!

Comment: ...athough I don't need any seperate options, I need the scrollbars to refresh after a specific action. It is not working though. any ideas?

Comment: Just updated my answer… To access the scrollbars you need to put them into a variable

Comment: Sorry that I come to this again.. So you create the scrollers, isn't there a way to control them all at once and not one by one individually? What I am looking for is this. I have collapsible elements inside the scrollers, and I want each one to be updated when a collapse event is triggered inside of it..