# Multiple iScroll elements on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch, iscroll

I'm making a mobile website with jQtouch and iScroll.

I wan't to get multiple scrollable areas with iScroll, but only of the lists works with iScroll...

I tried with this:

```
var scroll1, scroll2;
function loaded() {
   scroll1 = new iScroll('wrapper');
   scroll2 = new iScroll('list_wrapper');
}
```

But without luck.
Anyone have a solution that's working?

My html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="list_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me, I was having trouble with it too

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/7159687/903000

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this approach.

Html:

```
<div class="carousel" id="alt-indie">
    <div class="scroller">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            // etc
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.carousel').each(function (index) {
    new iScroll($(this).attr('id'), { /* options */ });
});
```

so anything with the class of "carousel" will become a slider.

Answer (score 0):

Your html seems correct,

make sure 'loaded' function is being called as wel.

Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scroll1, scroll2;

$("#you_might_like_index").live("pageshow", function() {

  setTimeout(function(){scroll1 = new iScroll('wrapper');}, 0);
  setTimeout(function(){scroll2 = new iScroll('list_wrapper');}, 0);
});

<div data-role="page" id="you_might_like_index">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="list_wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a bit late... but since I was stuck on the same problem, here's my solution, which works great.
Note: This solution requires jquery, but I am using it anyway.

The script part:

```
function iscroller_init () {
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    iscroller.each(function(index){
        $(this).addClass('iscroller'+index).attr('iscroller_id','iscroller'+index);
        var tmpfnc = new Function('var myScroll'+index);
        tmpfnc();
        var tmpfnc = new Function('myScroll'+index+' = new IScroll(\'.iscroller'+index+'\', { mouseWheel: true });');
        tmpfnc();
    });
}

function iscroller_reinit (el) {
    var el = $(el);
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    var i = iscroller.index(el);
    var tmpfnc = new Function('var myScroll'+i+' = new IScroll(\'.iscroller'+i+'\', { mouseWheel: true });');
    tmpfnc();
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.iscroller').length > 0) iscroller_init ();
});
```

The html:

```
<div class="scrollholder fl">
    <div class="iscroller">
        <div class="scroller">
            <ul>
                <li>Pretty row 1</li>
                <li>Pretty row 2</li>
                <li>Pretty row 3</li>
                <li>Pretty row 4</li>
                .....
                <li>Pretty row 47</li>
                <li>Pretty row 48</li>
                <li>Pretty row 49</li>
                <li>Pretty row 50</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

where the parent `<div class="scrollholder fl">`is the parent div, which can be positioned where you want, and multiple times.
Info: The class "fl" works as css separator for `"float:left;"` in my case and is not corresponding to any iscroll function.
The second function `iscroller_reinit (el)` is for reinitialisation of specified single iscroller, may be fired after the container was loaded by ajax request.