# Icroll.js Child Element overflow: scroll not working on IOS

Tags: ios, css, overflow, iscroll

Im using Iscroll.js for a project that requires all elements to fit the height of the screen with a large horizontal scroll. My issue is there are certain elements that overflow vertically depending on the amount of content they have.

I have used "overflow-y: scroll" on these elements and it works fine on desktop browsers but not on mobile.

I have tried the webkit prefix  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch but that also does not work.

the css for my vertical scroll elements is:

```
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

You can find the site at http://govanhillpeopleshistory.com/dev/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that interested I managed to fix this by reverting to IScrolll = and using multiple nested scrollers inside my main scroller. Used a similar solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976972/multiple-iscroll-elements-on-same-page).

Basically create an array to hold all of your IScroll objects, iterate over every element you want to be scrollable, grab its ID and and then create a  new array element and Iscroll Object using the ID you Grabbed. Heres my code:

```
          articleBottomState.find('.cards-wrapper').each(function(){ 

            $(this).find('.content-card').each(function(){
              //console.log(counter++);

              var currentCardID = '#' + this.id; //Get Scrollable Areas ID
              console.log(currentCardID);

              //Add another array element to the myscrollers array
              myscrollers[vertScrollCOunter++] = new IScroll(currentCardID, {
                scrollX: true, 
                scrollY: true, 
                mouseWheel: true,
                momentum: false
              });
            });

          });
```